# how to handle tcp connections on django

Tags: python, django

I have a django framework that receives user form. Thi input is used to create a TCP connection with a backhand process and send and receive json on it.

How do I handle several TCP connections using django framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Celery processes in the background and perhaps use the awesome Twisted library for handling your network requirements.